# Can't install any package due to error with library

Tags: package-management

I am trying to install libv4l-dev on my system, but I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libv4l-dev is already the newest version (1.10.0-1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cabextract chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gir1.2-gtk-2.0 gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers libass5 libatk1.0-dev libavcodec-dev libavcodec-extra libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56 libavformat-dev libavformat-ffmpeg56 libavresample-ffmpeg2 libavutil-dev libavutil-ffmpeg54 libbasicusageenvironment1 libbluray1
  libbs2b0 libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2-dev libcddb2 libchromaprint0 libcrystalhd3 libdc1394-22 libdc1394-22-dev libdca0 libde265-0 libdirectfb-1.2-9 libdvbpsi10 libebml4v5 libfaad2 libflite1 libfluidsynth1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev libgme0 libgroupsock8 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgtk2.0-dev libgtkglext1 libhal1-flash libharfbuzz-dev
  libharfbuzz-gobject0 libilmbase-dev libiso9660-8 libjpeg8-dev libkate1 liblivemedia50 libmatroska6v5 libmimic0 libmjpegutils-2.1-0 libmms0 libmodplug1 libmpcdec6 libmpeg2encpp-2.1-0 libmplex2-2.1-0 libmspack0 libofa0 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopenexr-dev libopenjpeg5 libpango1.0-dev libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libpostproc-ffmpeg53
  libproxy-tools libqt5x11extras5 libraw1394-dev libresid-builder0c2a libschroedinger-1.0-0 libsdl-image1.2 libshine3 libsidplay2v5 libsnappy1v5 libsoundtouch1 libsoxr0 libspandsp2 libsrtp0 libssh-gcrypt-4 libssh2-1 libswresample-dev libswresample-ffmpeg1 libswscale-dev libswscale-ffmpeg3 libtbb2 libunshield0 libupnp6 libusageenvironment3 libva-drm1
  libva-x11-1 libva1 libvcdinfo0 libvlc5 libvlccore8 libvncclient1 libvo-aacenc0 libvo-amrwbenc0 libwildmidi-config libwildmidi1 libx265-79 libxcb-composite0 libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb-xv0 libxvidcore4 libzbar0 libzvbi-common libzvbi0 oxideqt-codecs-extra unshield vlc vlc-data vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 317 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 78,9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 libjpeg62 amd64 1:6b2-2 [78,9 kB]
Fetched 78,9 kB in 0s (114 kB/s)     
dpkg: error processing package libjpeg62:amd64 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libjpeg62:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I can't remove or reinstall libjpeg62 because every time it throws the very same error.

What can I do and how did this happen?

Comment: have you tried 'sudo apt-get --reinstall install libjpeg62' to reinstall it?

Comment: very same error. It was a virtual machine tho. I dumped it and started new and everything smooth.